# Programmatically replace a tagged token

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace all instances in a Word Document of "[SomeVar]" with the value `dictionary("SomeVar")`

This is what I have so far

```
Public Sub ReplaceToken(ByVal range As range, ByVal dictionary As Scripting.dictionary)

  With range.Find
     .Text = "[*]"
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Format = False
     .MatchCase = False
     .MatchWholeWord = False
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .MatchSoundsLike = False
     .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With

  range.Find.Execute
  While range.Find.Found
    ' Nested Range ?????
    ' Range.Text = dictionary(Range.Text.withoutsquarebrackets) ???? 
  Wend

End Sub
```

I am uncertain how to perform the actual replacement because it seems to imply a nested call on `range` - If I `ReplaceAll` (which I want to do), what happens?

Sorry for the nooby question but I dont do much VBA these days

Answer (score 1):

Hugh, you can use the `Find.Execute` `Replace()` parameter instead:

```
Public Sub ReplaceTokens(ByVal range As range, ByVal dictionary As Scripting.dictionary)
    For Each Key In dictionary.Keys
    With range.Find
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = Key
        With .Replacement
            .Text = dictionary.Item(Key)
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub TestReplace()
Dim MyDict As New Scripting.dictionary
MyDict.Add Key:="REPLACE_ME", Item:="Replacement"
MyDict.Add Key:="REPLACE_ME_2", Item:="Replacement2"
Dim rng As range
Set rng = ThisDocument.range(0, 0)
    ReplaceTokens rng, MyDict
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to avoid cycling through the dictionary items if I can because I expect there to be very few matches, but a lot of dictionary items